# Azure Mobile Service or ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, xamarin.android, azure-sql-database

I am building an Android and Windows Phone application and the database is stored on the cloud. Now I want to access the tables on my application, please tell me that what is the best way to do that and which to use Azure Mobile Service or should I write my own ASP.NET Web API?. Please help me as I am new to these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Azure App Service Mobile app. It gives you lot of built in features which are mobile app specific such as integrated authentication with Facebook, twitter, google and microsoft accounts, you can use cross platform frameworks like Xamarin or phonegap. You can use offline data sync, personalized push notification and automated scaling as well.

You can do all this with a ASP.Net web API as well but their you will have to build all this yourself whereas Azure Mobile app gives these features out of the box. 
Check this to start with https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/

Comment: But i have my own database and also if i use azure then i have to write custom authentication because i have to authenticate the username and password with user table

Comment: With Asp.net i guess its easy to use ADO.NET for handling these kind of requests

Comment: In that case, you can try Web App/ API app on Azure as well if you just need to host your backend services. The reason I was recommending Mobile app is mainly for features like notifications and offline sync which are important for any mobile app and are in built.

Comment: yes i understand now, you are recommending me that i should write my own web service and then i should host it on azure?

Comment: You can still use Mobile app and connect to your cloud database and not use built in authentications and still use other features. The point is underneath all these app services run on Web APIs and depending on where you are using them they have different add on features

Comment: So I can write my own web api service for authentication and then use Azure app service mobile app for all other operations?

Comment: Yes you can. for the first purpose you can look into Azure app service API apps as well.

Comment: Do you have any sample article which shows this process?